# Show zeroes in a Regular Expression decimal

Tags: regular-language

Can someone tell me how to get the zeroes to show in a regular Expression containing zeroes for decimals.

For Example 1,320.00  When I turn it to a Regular Expression the .00 disappears. I need them to show.  Here is the formula I was working with.

```
(^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to capture?

Comment: I want it to show 1,320.00 including the zeroes.  Need the commas and the zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pattern which will capture the full number, including commas and decimals:

```
^(\d{1,3},)*\d{1,3}\.\d\d$
```

The first group, `(\d{1,3),)`, will match groups of one to three digits followed by a comma. It is followed by a `*`, so the pattern will match 0 or more of these groups (i.e. it will still match `320.00` and `12,312,122.00`).

The second part, `\d{1,3}\.`, will match the 1-3 digits preceding the decimal point.

Finally, `\d\d$` match the two decimal points. It looked like you're trying to match US currency, so I hard-coded in 2 digits for readability, but if you need to match, say, one or more decimal points, try this:

```
^(\d{1,3},)*\d{1,3}\.\d+$
```

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CvWUxM/1/).

Comment: Thanks Will, it is much appreciated.  Still trying to work through Regular Expressions.